# Is it possible to write an SQL Condition where it compares the bp master address to the sales order address to give an error?

Tags: c#, sql, sapb1

A more detailed version of the question is that in the B1 Validation Configuration, is there such a way for a sql condition if the sales order ship to address is not the same as the bp master data address, it would give you an error message stating that the bp master data address was changed, please fix it.

Im assuming its possible to do a C# as well with a basic sql condition whether it chooses one condition result or the other. like if this condition result1 else this condition result 2

sql or c# code is fine.

To explain further.

1. Existing Sales Order

2)BP master data address is changed

The existing Sales Order address is not changed to match the bp master data.

I want to add a condition into **B1 Validation Configuration** in the Sales Order and Delivery Order for a comparison into the "SQL Condition" with the bp master data and the sales order address. If its correct execute normally(condition result) , else error message must fix (condition result)

```
SELECT        h.DocEntry, h.DocNum, h.CardCode, h.CardName, h.DocDate, h.DocDueDate, ao.StreetS AS [Street in Order], ac.Street AS [Street in Master Data], ao.ZipCodeS AS [ZipCode in Order], ac.ZipCode AS [ZipCode in Master Data], 
                         ao.CityS AS [City in Order], ac.City AS [City in Master Data], ao.CountryS AS [Country in Order], ac.Country AS [Country in Master Data], ac.State AS [State in Master Data], ao.StateS AS [State in Order], 
                         ac.Block AS [Block in Master Data], ao.BlockS AS [Block in Order]
FROM            dbo.ORDR AS h INNER JOIN
                         dbo.RDR12 AS ao ON h.DocEntry = ao.DocEntry INNER JOIN
                         dbo.OCRD AS c ON h.CardCode = c.CardCode INNER JOIN
                         dbo.CRD1 AS ac ON c.CardCode = ac.CardCode AND ac.Address = 'Ship to'
WHERE        (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (ao.StreetS <> ac.Street) OR
                         (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (ao.ZipCodeS <> ac.ZipCode) OR
                         (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (ao.CityS <> ac.City) OR
                         (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (ao.CountryS <> ac.Country) OR
                         (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (ao.StateS <> ac.State) OR
                         (h.DocStatus = 'O') AND (ao.BlockS <> ac.Block)
```

So this is the sql data that im trying to input into the condition where it checks if it matches or not.
[image]
[image]

Comment: `if(a != b){throw new Exception("You have a problem");}` If you want more specifics, you are going to have to provide more details, including what you have tried so far.

Comment: so how do you connect a to the business partner address and b for the sales order ship to address in the business configuration validation?

Comment: It would be  helpful to see what code you have tried so far and from there we as a community could make recommendations.

Comment: added code, in the b1 validation configuration, its essentially an error checker to see if you have done this or done that. So I want to do the same thing where it compares the sales order address to the bp master data address. And if the comparison addresses are correct, you are able to execute normally, otherwise it stops you and sends you a message saying that the bp master data was changed and needs to be updated in the sales order